# How do I correctly read and print an accented character from SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, special-characters

hi I have an iPhone app database created in in sqlite

in database there is a word crème  (with special character ( è )

but when retrieving this word using select statement it is showing as in log

[image]

and in table view cell

[image]

so how to print special character " è "  in tableview cell ?

Comment: try something like this: `str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"è"];` where è could by any other char*

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/221a/index.htm

Comment: \U00e8 http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e8/index.htm

Comment: as richard pointed out, the enconding of your string is incorrect. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e8/index.htm you should have something like `cr\U00e8me` for `crème`

Comment: in 'C' if your source text is in the same encoding that your output is in you can type "crème"

Comment: @Prerak: I think you need to study NSUTF8 Encoding. I think this is done in Glossary and Opposites Day :)

Answer (score 4):

use this to get data from database -

```
NSString *col1 = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and display the col1 in a UILabel.

Don't believe on NSLog it will show unicode chars as \U221a or something like this.. just pass these strings to UILabel and you are good to go

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the string to a CString in Latin encoding and then reconvert the cstring to utf-8

```
NSString *notes = [item objectForKey:@"notes"] ;

const char *n_c_string =[notes cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];        
NSString *n = [NSString stringWithCString:notes_c_string encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```